# Why does the FirstThread always run before the SecondThread in the following code?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class TowThreads {
    public static class FirstThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 2; i < 100000; i++) {
                if (isPrime(i)) {
                    System.out.println("A");
                    System.out.println("B");
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean isPrime(int i) {
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static class SecondThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            for (int j = 2; j < 100000; j++) {
                if (isPrime(j)) {
                    System.out.println("1");
                    System.out.println("2");
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean isPrime(int i) {
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FirstThread().run();
        new SecondThread().run();
    }
}
```

The output shows that the FirstThread always runs before the SecondThread which is opposite from [the article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-threads/section3.html) I read.

Why?Must the first thread run before the second thread? If not, could you show me a good example? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use start not run

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FirstThread().start();
        new SecondThread().start();
    }
```

If you use run method, you call first method and after second method. If you want to run parallel threads, you must use start method of thread.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the machine processor and jvm how they schedule your threads. Even in the article you have read it is clearly mentioned

*"Not only may the results vary from machine to machine, but running the same program multiple times on the same machine may produce different results. Never assume one thread will do something before another thread does, unless you've used synchronization to force a specific ordering of execution"*

you can't expect threads to behave in same way on all machines. It all depends how the machine schedules them.

Comment: I think run code gives ABABABABAB......121212121212 but expected is ABAB1212AB12AB12AB12A1B2

Comment: you are right. calling run() method makes call like calling normal methods so works accordingly but if we want to run them simultaneously then we need to call using start() method. but still behaviour of threads on different machines can be different.